# "vagrant up" not working on Windows 7 behind firewall

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I am very new to Vagrant and VirtualBox. I have installed both of these and cloned the necessary directory with the following command:

> git clone https://github.com/scotch-io/scotch-box.git my-project

But when I run "vagrant up", it fails and shows the following message:

> Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
>   ==> default: Box 'scotch/box' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
>       default: Box Provider: virtualbox
>       default: Box Version: >= 0 The box 'scotch/box' could not be found or could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
>   box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via `vagrant
>   login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded URL and error
>   message are shown below:
>
> URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/scotch/box"] Error: Failed connect
>   to atlas.hashicorp.com:443; No error

I am on Windows 7 computer and I am behind a firewall. My VirtualBox version is 5.0.10 and Vagrant version is 1.7.3.

Can someone please help to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is that you don't have *Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package* installed on your system.

The easiest way to install it is to use chocolatey (https://chocolatey.org/). You can find the instructions on the web page, but here's a resume of what you should do:

1. Open a command prompt as administrator and paste the following to install chocolatey:

   ```
   @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin
   ```
2. Install vcredist2010 using the following command (again, as administrator):

   ```
   choco install -y vcredist2010
   ```
3. You're ready to go, now `vagrant up` should run without problems.

Also, make sure that the path to the Vagrant home folder does not have any spaces on it, this will give you more than one headache. See [this](https://gist.github.com/michaelklapper/4943139#file-virtualbox_vagrant_home-bat) for some help changing it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package installed. Please see the image here which shows the package installed in my PC. Thanks. http://postimg.org/image/duevy7p7z/

Comment: As the problem of connecting to the server persists, you should verify that you can connect and you don't have the firewall blocking it. You can do that using [openssl](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/gnuwin32/openssl-0.9.8h-1-bin.zip) with the following command (executable is in the `bin` folder): `openssl.exe s_client -connect atlas.hashicorp.com:443` and see if it throws an error.